How reading data from pivot model to check if some Id found in result set?
On Laravel 11 site User model has pivot reference to tasks table
public function uncompletedTasks(): belongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class)
        ->using(TaskUser::class)
        ->withPivot('supervisor_id')   // Reference to "task_user" table
        ->where('completed',false)
        ->orderBy('priority', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('deadline_at', 'desc');
    }

and I need having $taskId to check if it exists in read data, something like :
$uncompletedTasks = LoggedUserFacade::getLoggedUser()->uncompletedTasks()->get()->findOrFail($taskId);

as in request above method findOrFail does not exists!
I searched in helpers at  https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/helpers, but I did not find any decision...
Sure I know how to check it in foreach block, but maybe some better decision ?
Are there any ?
"laravel/framework": "^11.10.0",


$user = LoggedUserFacade::getLoggedUser();
$taskId = 123;

$uncompletedTasks = $user->uncompletedTasks()->get();
$task = $uncompletedTasks->find($taskId);

if ($task) {
    echo "Task with ID $taskId exists in the user's uncompleted tasks.";
    echo "Task details: " . $task->title . " (" . $task->deadline_at . ")";
} else {
    echo "Task with ID $taskId not found in the user's uncompleted tasks.";
}


With your code I got error Call to undefined method App\Models\Task::tasks()
I suppose that is referenced to ->whereHas('tasks',  block .Actually do I really need this block ?

i have updated please consider now

No way to make 2 requests in 1  ?
